# Unexpected keyword in sublime text 3 when using a package command

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

## Introduction

I am developping a sublime text 3 package.

Suddenly, the command I am adding the the package broke. It throws every time the following error in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Lib\python33\sublime_plugin.py", line 1456, in run_
    return self.run(**args)
TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'redeploy_module'
```

This appears in "dirty" sublime as well as in clean state.

This happens when I add a list input handler.

### This works

```py
class ProjectNameInputHandler(sublime_plugin.TextInputHandler):
    def placeholder(self):
        return "Project's name - must already exist"

    # def next_input(self, args):
    #     if 'module' not in args:
    #         return RedeployModuleInputHandler()


# class RedeployModuleInputHandler(sublime_plugin.ListInputHandler):
#     def placeholder(self):
#         return "Module to create template for"

#     def list_items(self):
#         return [("Manager (v1)", "manager"),
#                 ("Projects (v2)", "projects")]


class RedeployJobCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, project_name):

        plugin_path = str(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        template_cli = "\"{}\\template-python-cli\\cli.py\""\
            .format(plugin_path)

        folder = self.window.extract_variables()['folder']
        args = "redeployJob {}".format(project_name)
        command = "echo 'python {} {}'".format(template_cli, args)
        self.window.run_command("exec", {
            "shell_cmd": command,
            "working_dir": folder
        })

    def input(self, args):
        if 'project_name' not in args:
            return ProjectNameInputHandler()
        # elif 'module' not in args:
        #     return RedeployModuleInputHandler()
```

### This does not work

```py
import sublime_plugin
import os


class ProjectNameInputHandler(sublime_plugin.TextInputHandler):
    def placeholder(self):
        return "Project's name - must already exist"

    def next_input(self, args):
        if 'module' not in args:
            return RedeployModuleInputHandler()


class RedeployModuleInputHandler(sublime_plugin.ListInputHandler):
    def placeholder(self):
        return "Module to create template for"

    def list_items(self):
        return [("Manager (v1)", "manager"),
                ("Projects (v2)", "projects")]


class RedeployJobCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, project_name, module):

        plugin_path = str(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        template_cli = "\"{}\\template-python-cli\\cli.py\""\
            .format(plugin_path)

        folder = self.window.extract_variables()['folder']
        args = "redeployJob {}".format(project_name)
        command = "echo 'python {} {}'".format(template_cli, args)
        self.window.run_command("exec", {
            "shell_cmd": command,
            "working_dir": folder
        })

    def input(self, args):
        if 'project_name' not in args:
            return ProjectNameInputHandler()
        elif 'module' not in args:
            return RedeployModuleInputHandler()
```

It throws the error described in the introduction.

I do not understand why it does that. What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

In

```
def run(self, project_name, module):
```

rename `module` to `redeploy_module`

```
def run(self, project_name, redeploy_module):
```